# Unable to debug FireBreath plugin APIs using Visual Studio

Tags: firebreath

I have tried the mentioned **steps** to debug my FB plugin and I am unable to put a break point in the Plugin APIs.

**Steps**:

1) Launch a “sample page” on Firefox browser which loads my FB plugin.

2) Go to Debug -> "Attach to Process" in Visual studio 2008.

3) Attach the FireFox.exe process which has the “sample page” title.

4) Unable to put a breakpoint in the plugin API as my plugin DLL symbols are not loaded in Visual Studio.

I am not sure why my Plugin DLL symbols are not loaded. Please help me out.

NOTE: FB Plugin is built in Debug mode.

Thank you, Sande

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that firefox runs plugins in a seperate process; I think it's called something like plugin_container.exe

More info on [FireBreath's debugging plugins page](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Debugging+Plugins)

Comment: great; mark it as the answer, then! (green outline of a check box)